# Creating instances of 2 child classes with the same parent

Tags: php, oop, class

I basically have two child classes which have the same parent class.

what I wish to do is create instances of both classes in one script in order to access some of their unique functions, im very rusty on this subject but it seems that it is not possible.

I get the error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MWS`

I want to know what is the proper way to work around this?

Below is an example of my class structure

**Parent class**

```
class MWS{
   funcion MWS(){}
}
```

**Child class**

```
require_once('mws.php');

class MWS_Orders extends MWS{
   function MWS_Orders(){}
}
```

**Child class**

```
require_once('mws.php');

class MWS_Feed extends MWS{
    function MWS_Feed(){}
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once('mws_feed.php');
require_once('mws_orders.php');

$feed = new MWS_Feed();
$orders = new MWS_Orders();
```

Comment: does the code that you based your example on give you any errors?

Comment: Should be doable, do you get any errors or what isn't working?

Comment: yes i get the following error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MWS`

Comment: this happens because both child classes require their parent file e.g. `include('mws.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the declaration of the parent class in its own file and `require_once()` that file. Do not declare the parent class in each of the child class files and do not use `require()` instead of `require_once()`.